# Fast web frameworks for use with Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi

I have a Raspberry Pi 3B+ at home running a dockerized NextCloud instance. It runs fine, but of course the Pi’s computing power limits what I would want to deploy on that machine.

Lately, I’ve not not only been thinking about building a little web app for myself with Django, but also took a small dive into the world of Go, and now I ask myself how much I could profit of Go’s efficiency in a framework like Buffalo - but either my google skills suffice to find any numbers on this topic or nobody has dealt with it?

So what I’m asking is if anybody can supply some figures on **how much better web frameworks written in Go would perform running in a Docker container on a recent Raspberry Pi**. I am not sure if running the software inside of docker already eats all the advantages away or maybe the biggest bottleneck in modern web frameworks is waiting for requests over the network, where increased execution speed does not change a tat.

Comment: To be blunt - I think your question may be flawed. You won't find these numbers because they don't mean anything. As you can see from framework tests, see Go being some of the slowest frameworks, and some of the fastest: https://www.techempower.com/benchmarks/#section=data-r17&hw=ph&test=plaintext&c=2

Comment: Be blunt, I can take it. ;)

Let me refine my question a little: Has anybody ever compared e.g. response times of different web frameworks (in a docker setup) on the somewhat special platform the Raspberry Pi provides?

Comment: What do you mean by response times? TTFB or render speed of plaintext response? Again, I don't think you're going to find an answer in general. Maybe you should consider asking things like how Docker's network abstraction would cause degraded performance, or why ARM is slower than x86 processors in the same tasks. Asking for the fastest doesn't help much because there's a lot of pros/cons to languages/runtimes. Example, CSS/HTML is turing complete, but you wouldn't build any non-trivial app on it. Java is incredibly performant in huge applications, but is slow to start.